# Copy to a dynamic range without the clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste values to a dynamic range on a different worksheet without using the clipboard. When the code gets to the Range=Range part it errors out stating, "Application-defined or object-defined error." Any ideas?

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Start As Worksheet
Dim ED As Worksheet
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, r1 As Integer, c1 As Integer

Set Start = Sheets("Start")
Set ED = Sheets("End")

r = 1
c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count



With Start
    Do Until .Cells(r, c).Value = ""
        r = r + 1

    Loop
    r = r - 1

End With
 r1 = 1
 c1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

With ED

    Do Until .Cells(r1, c1).Value = ""
        r1 = r1 + 1

    Loop
    r1 = r1

 Range(Cells(r1, 1), Cells(r1 + r - 1, c1)) = Start.Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(1, 1))

 Start.Activate
```

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(r1, 1), .Cells(r1 + r - 1, c1)).Value = Start.Range(Start.Cells(r, c), Start.Cells(1, 1)).Value`  Qualify ***EVERY*** Range object with its parent sheet.

Answer (score 3):

1. **ALWAYS** qualify every parent to every Range Object.  The `Cells()` inside the Range() needs to be pointed at the same parent:

> `Start.Range(Start.Cells(r, c), Start.Cells(1, 1))`

2. We do not need loops but can use `END()` to find the last columns and rows.

Replace:

```
Do Until .Cells(r, c).Value = ""
    r = r + 1

Loop
r = r - 1
```

With:

```
c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
```

3. Use Resize, it is shorter and easier to maintain:

> `.Cells(r1+1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value = Start.Cells(1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value`

So:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Start As Worksheet
Dim ED As Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long, r1 As Long, c1 As Long

Set Start = Sheets("Start")
Set ED = Sheets("End")

With Start
    c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With ED
    c1 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    r1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(r1+1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value = Start.Cells(1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value
End With
```

Comment: Success! I knew it was a small detail like that. Appreciate the help/feed back!